# why php end() function not working when i give explode() function inside an end() function?

Tags: php

when i use function like this it works

```
function activeClass(){
    $link = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo end($link);
}
activeClass();
```

but when i try to use the same function like this

```
function activeClass(){
    echo end(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}
activeClass();
```

it shows a notice

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\php7\htdocs\autosuggest\link.php on line 4

Comment: Store explode in variable `$exp = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` and then `end($exp)`

Comment: this is exactly what i did.. i am just curious to know why?

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: using php 7.0.9

Answer (score 2):

You should have a warning message like : Only variables should be passed by reference.

It's because the [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function waits for the **reference** of the array because this function will **modify** your variable. This is why you have to pass a **declared** variable in the PHP scope.

Comment: no i dont get any warning just a parse error which i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: I havn't this error when I try your code in a PHP 7 file

Comment: yes if i try using php 7 i receive a notice like this "Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\php7\htdocs\autosuggest\link.php on line 4" and i did receive the output.

Comment: I hope my answer will explain you why this is not working ;-)

Comment: Glad to help you ;-) Could you accept my answer then ?

Answer (score 0):

As  [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) says about parameter for `end()` function:

> This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the
>   function.     This means you must pass it a real variable and not a
>   function returning an array because only actual variables may be
>   passed by reference.